# Forcing http using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is the script I have right now, how do I have my script force all traffic to http, currently it is doing the exact opposite, it is forcing all traffic to https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I've also tried this and it didn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP} !=on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I got this error:

> Too many redirects occurred trying to open www.blankpage.com .

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You want to check that HTTPS is **on**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And if it is on (`%{HTTPS} on`), redirect to `http://`. There is no mod_rewrite variable called `%{HTTP}`, only `%{HTTPS}` which can be "on" or "off".

The reason why you were getting the too many redirects error is because:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP} !=on
```

is always true no matter if the request is http or https, since the variable doesn't exist, it will *never* be equal to "on". Therefore, even if the request is http, you keep getting redirected to the same URL (http).

Comment: Don't know why it is not working for me. I did a simple test like below putting it on the first line of my .htaccess, but still getting alert from browser when I input `https://example.com`

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .* https://google.com [L]`

Answer (score 0):

In the processwire htaccess look for these lines

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**If you only want to allow HTTPS, uncomment the RewriteCond and RewriteRule lines below**.

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**If you only want to allow HTTP use the code below**

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```