# .Htaccess index php / html redirect to main page

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess.
I would like:

- That he would direct from [www.domena.pl](http://www.domena.pl) to domena.pl (I have it done)
  to always point to https
- after entering domena.pl/index php or index html -> redirected to https domena.pl

How can I make it?

My htacess:

```
  RewriteEngine On
     # Redirect to non www
     RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ www.domena.pl $ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Https://domena.pl/$1 [R = 301, L]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230909/forcing-http-using-htaccess does this answer your question?

Comment: @GertB I have redirect from www to none www and https. I need redirect from domain.com/index.php / index.html to domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to non-www with https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

To let all routes go to index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```